# How to fix "AttributeError: module 'chart_studio.tools' has no attribute 'make_subplots'"

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I am using python 3.7, plotly 3.8.1 and cufflinks 0.15 and got the below error, please kindly help.

Ipython code -

```
calls.set_index('STRIKE_PRC')[['CF_CLOSE', 'IMP_VOLT']].iplot(subplots=True,
                                                             mode='lines+markers',size=6)
```

error code-

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>
> C:\Users\George
>   Lo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\cufflinks\tools.py in
>   get_subplots(rows, cols, shared_xaxes, shared_yaxes, start_cell,
>   theme, base_layout, **kwargs)
>       892 
>       893         layout= base_layout if base_layout else getLayout(theme,**check_kwargs(kwargs,__LAYOUT_AXIS))
>   --> 894   sp=py.plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=rows,cols=cols,shared_xaxes=shared_xaxes,
>       895                                                                                    shared_yaxes=shared_yaxes,print_grid=False,
>       896                                           start_cell=start_cell,**kwargs)
>
> AttributeError: module 'chart_studio.tools' has no attribute
>   'make_subplots'

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug with integration between plotly 3.8.X and was reported on the [cufflinks github issue tracker](https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/175). A fix was merged, but I don't think that it is released yet.

Edit: 09/05/19 and 21/06/19 Updated my conda environment, but the bug remains.

Comment: Is there any way around this issue? Downgrading Plotly?